# Fetch row from one of the two tables in sql

Tags: sql

Consider two tables: TableA and TableB with columns as,
TableA - (col1a, col2a, col3a)
TableB - (col1b, col2b, col3b).
I have one key which is either present in TableA or TableB. Based on the presence of the key in either of the table, I have to query one of the respective table. Is it possible using sql ?

Comment: What database?  If the row is mutually exclusive between the two tables, use a UNION clause.

Comment: Of course you can query each of the tables separately and see where you find a record, but I take your question to mean that you want to do it in a single query... right?

Comment: yes, in a single query. Database: Oracle. 
 i am trying to insert value in table3 whose value might come from either table1 or table2 with the key that i have. Note: Key is present in either of the table and not both, so dont worry about the edge cAse

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single query, you can create a database function and pass key to the function and perform table selection and data extraction in that function.

And after this you can call the database functions from your code. Please refer to database manual for creating functions as they can be optimized for the database.

Comment: i need this in a single query, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with pseudo-code like that is that it's unclear exactly how your data is structured. You said the key can be in either table, but you aren't clear if it could be in any of the 3 columns in either table. You also don't indicate the data type of the key or the columns. Additionally, I'd recommend not using such simplified column names - unless that was just your pseudo-code.

That being said, assuming that the key could exist in any column in either table, here's a sample of how you could union multiple SELECT statements looking for the key in any one of the 6 columns across the two tables.
    DECLARE @TableA TABLE
    (
        col1a VARCHAR(10)
    ,   col2a VARCHAR(10)
    ,   col3a VARCHAR(10)
    )

```
INSERT INTO @TableA
    (   col1a
    ,   col2a
    ,   col3a )
VALUES
    ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
INSERT INTO @TableA
    (   col1a
    ,   col2a
    ,   col3a )
VALUES
    ('key4', 'key5', 'key6')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE
(
    col1b VARCHAR(10)
,   col2b VARCHAR(10)
,   col3b VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @TableB
    (   col1b
    ,   col2b
    ,   col3b )
VALUES
    ('key7', 'key8', 'key9');
INSERT INTO @TableB
    (   col1b
    ,   col2b
    ,   col3b )
VALUES
    ('key10', 'key11', 'key12');

DECLARE @SearchKey VARCHAR(10) = 'key6'

SELECT * FROM @TableA WHERE col1a = @SearchKey
UNION
SELECT * FROM @TableA WHERE col2a = @SearchKey
UNION
SELECT * FROM @TableA WHERE col3a = @SearchKey
UNION
SELECT * FROM @TableB WHERE col1b = @SearchKey
UNION
SELECT * FROM @TableB WHERE col2b = @SearchKey
UNION
SELECT * FROM @TableB WHERE col3b = @SearchKey
```